# I have 'Error in normalizePath' in visNetwork R

Tags: r, visnetwork

I'm trying to generate a graph with the VisNetwork package of R. But I got the error

```
Error in normalizePath(target_dir, "/", TRUE) :
  path[1]="query/htmlwidgets-1.2": No such file or directory
```

The code I've written is :

```
visNetwork(nodes = nodes, edges = edges, width = "100%", height = 900,
                     main = list( 
                       style =  'font:caption;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-align:center;'))  %>%
        visPhysics(solver = "forceAtlas2Based", 
                   stabilization = T,
                   timestep=0.25,
                   forceAtlas2Based = list(gravitationalConstant = -50, avoidOverlap = 0.95)) %>%
        visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE) %>%
        visEdges(smooth = T) %>%
        visNodes(scaling = list(min = 10, max = 40))%>%
        visSave(file = save_name, background = "white",selfcontained = T)
    }
```

The error appears when I set save_name to any directory different from **'./'** .
But what is more Surprising is that I can't find the generated file anywhere.

Can anyone help me to solve this so I can set the path I want ?

Thanks

Comment: What values of `save_name` fail?

Comment: Any other than './'. Ex: "/sem/pahers/bigdata/delhalim.html"

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help troubleshoot and recognize issues like this, so bear with me here: please verify `file.exists("/sem/pahers/bigdata/delhalim.html")` and, if true, verify `dir.exists("/sem/pahers")` (and then `".../bigdata"` too).

Comment: The file delhalim.html does not exist because the code have to create it. So it’s a bit difficult. When I set the path to './' , the code works, but the file delhalim.html is unfindable.

Comment: What about all of the paths before it? If `"/sem/pahers/bigdata/"` does not exist, then you cannot create a file within it.

Comment: The path exists and is right. I've just found the solution. The problem was a folder with numbers as name in the path.  I've just drop it and it works. I figure out that R struggle with path. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use paths with numbers every day, never seen or heard of a problem there. R on Windows _does_ have problems with spaces in the path name (often, not always), however. There are also problems on windows with network drives and/or network "mounts" (e.g., dropbox, onedrive, owncloud/nextcloud).